# How to add to the right of the datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a DataTables and below a chart.

I have this :

[image]

Here is my Html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Css/jquery.visualize.plugin.css" />
</head>
<body>
<table id="table_statistic_1" class="display">
    <caption style="font-size: 20px">Omzetcijfer per geografische zone</caption>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

After filling the DataTables, I put the chart.

`$('table').visualize({ type: 'line' });`

I would like to add my chart to the right of my DataTables. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I saw that the datatables loaded a ***dataTables_wrapper*** that took up the entire width of my page and therefore my graph is displayed below.

I then added div tags for the dataTables and the graph as a css `float left` and I have a container which includes these 2 tag div. I place the tags div tags left and right with `width :50%`

Html code :

```
<div id="left">
<table id="table_statistic_1" class="display">
    <caption  class ="caption">Omzetcijfer per geografische zone</caption>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div id="right"></div>
```

Css code :

```
.container { display:block; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; height:400px; }
#left, #right{ float:left; display:block; margin:0; padding:0; width:50%; height:400px;}
```